# Chrome does not seem to read CSS files fully

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a CSS file that has more than 300 lines. A number of html and PHP files use this CSS as external stylesheet and all this works fine if opened from my local drive.

However, once installed on the remote web server, entries after the 300th line in the CSS file do not take effect. This issue occurs only on Google Chrome (Version 52.0.2743.116) and not in IE, Edge or Firefox browsers. The workaround is to adopt internal / inline styling for the specific ids and classes in each of the html/php files.

While I have reported the issue to Google, I would appreciate any suggestions to resolve this issue from the developers' end. Thanks.

Comment: its doesn't have an issue with chrome may be that version have a bug, can you update or clean the cache?

Comment: I never had that problem, so I would assume that it is a problem of the server where you host your webpage (because it works locally) or probably with an extension you have install with chrome.

Comment: just split the CSS file into multiple ones?

Comment: If Google Chrome really had an issue with 300+ lines of CSS, that's totally screwed Bootstrap [unminified] @ 3k+ lines. Is your server cutting off the file?

Comment: If it works fine locally but not on the web server, why do you think the issue is a Chrome one?

Comment: @ca8msm because other browsers do not display the issue as detailed in the question.

Comment: What does Chrome Code Inspector tell you, is the CSS source code being passed to the Browser, can you open and read beyond line 300? Are there any console errors such as CSS syntax errors in your style file?

Comment: @Martin I read the question as though it works in Chrome locally, but not in Chrome when on the web server which IMO would not make it a Chrome issue?

Comment: Note that other browsers (IE, Firefox, Edge) work fine on the web server. Further no errors in the style file beyond line 300 as the same lines work fine when copied inline html.

Comment: Can you show us the CSS file, or link to it?